TreeMap, private void deleteEntry(Entry<K,V> p) replacement case
please look at this piece of code
            // Fix replacement
            if (p.color == BLACK)
                fixAfterDeletion(replacement);

Below is the full method code
    /**
     * Delete node p, and then rebalance the tree.
     */
    private void deleteEntry(Entry<K,V> p) {
        modCount++;
        size--;

        // If strictly internal, copy successor's element to p and then make p
        // point to successor.
        if (p.left != null && p.right != null) {
            Entry<K,V> s = successor(p);
            p.key = s.key;
            p.value = s.value;
            p = s;
        } // p has 2 children

        // Start fixup at replacement node, if it exists.
        Entry<K,V> replacement = (p.left != null ? p.left : p.right);

        if (replacement != null) {
            // Link replacement to parent
            replacement.parent = p.parent;
            if (p.parent == null)
                root = replacement;
            else if (p == p.parent.left)
                p.parent.left  = replacement;
            else
                p.parent.right = replacement;

            // Null out links so they are OK to use by fixAfterDeletion.
            p.left = p.right = p.parent = null;

            // Fix replacement
            if (p.color == BLACK)
                fixAfterDeletion(replacement);
        } else if (p.parent == null) { // return if we are the only node.
            root = null;
        } else { //  No children. Use self as phantom replacement and unlink.
            if (p.color == BLACK)
                fixAfterDeletion(p);

            if (p.parent != null) {
                if (p == p.parent.left)
                    p.parent.left = null;
                else if (p == p.parent.right)
                    p.parent.right = null;
                p.parent = null;
            }
        }
    }

so the question :  why do we do the check as shown in the first block of code, if before that we do the check:
    if (replacement != null) {

and therefore if the replacement is != null then the only possible case is that “p” is exactly black with one red replacement
and after that we change the replacement to black in the method:
fixAfterDeletion(replacement);

and we must call
fixAfterDeletion(replacement);

just to do this:
setColor(x, BLACK);

I couldn’t figure this out myself, please help me understand this case
